# Kol Isha and transgender people

Tags: halacha, contemporary-halacha, leniencies, kol-isha, gender-identity

Does the Halachic prohibition of Kol Isha apply to transgender people? So if a woman underwent operations to present as a man, can you listen to her sing? And what about a man who visibly looks like a woman? The reason I ask is because although gender in Halacha starts at birth, Kol Isha (to my understanding) is only Derabbanan so many opinions say the prohibition applies when you see the opposite gender person, not merely hear them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following our discussion in comments, I discussed your question with R Binyamin Tabady, a *posek halacha* in Israel, who confirmed my initial thoughts.

The obligation of *kol isha* is on the listener. Since halakha doesn't recognize gender changes, **a man remains forbidden to listen to the voice of a biological woman, even if that person calls herself a man**, or had surgery to look more like a man.

Similarly, a man who looks like a woman would not create an issue of *kol isha* is other men listened to that person sing.

The issue might theoretically be different if the transgender person had vocal cord surgery which resulted in his voice being different, although that requires further study.

For further sources see [here](https://www.eshelonline.org/transeshel/), [here](https://aish.com/kol_isha/) and [here](https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/studies-halakha/women-and-mitzvot/kol-isha-i-halakhic-basis).

Comment: What happens if the listener thinks he is listening to a biological woman when he isn't?  Does that make any difference?

Comment: Vocal cord surgery isn't always necessary for a person to change their voice from female-sounding to male-sounding or vice versa. A person with a female-sounding voice who takes testosterone as a medication will generally end up having a male-sounding voice as a result. A person with a male-sounding voice can perform training techniques which result in the ability to sing or speak with a female-sounding voice.

Comment: @MosesSupposes the answer takes the route that kol Isha is objective not subjective

Comment: @RabbiKaii It might not technically be kol ishah then, but surely even then it is a problem for a person to do an action that they believe is an aveirah, and surely it is even more of a problem then if the listener is attracted as a result!?

Comment: @MosesSupposes sure, but that would likely be lifnei iver and lo taturu respectively, not kol isha